# Spring Boot Web starter views location

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I tried to make a simple Spring Boot web application:

POM:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Main class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"controller"})
@Import(MvcConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/helloView")
    public String helloView(){
        return "homeView";
    }
}
```

Also under `src/main` i got

```
src
   -main
       -resources
            applicaion.properties
       -webapp
            -WEB-INF
                 -jsp
                     -homeView.jsp
```

In application.properties I got:

```
  spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
  spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

The rest endpoint `/home/hello` works, but the other one can't open the jsp. 
In the log i got

```
Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/homeView.jsp
Did not find handler method for [/WEB-INF/jsp/homeView.jsp]
```

Where should I put the views so the app can find them?

Comment: Have a look at the following example from Spring Boot's github repository https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to geoand's answer I added

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

to the pom and it worked.